# Add days to date in Go

Tags: go

I'm trying to add a number of days (actually a number of weeks) to an existing date in Go. I have tried 
`myDate.Add(time.Hour * 24 * 7 * weeksToAdd)`

But I get an error when I try to build: `invalid operation: time.Hour * startAdd (mismatched types time.Duration and float64)`

So `weeksToAdd` is currently a `float64`, but I can change it to an int or whatever. Changing it to an int only changed my error to say that `int` and `Duration` can't be multiplied.

How do I add days to a date?

Answer (score 121, accepted):

Use [`Time.AddDate()`](https://golang.org/pkg/time/#Time.AddDate):

```
func (t Time) AddDate(years int, months int, days int) Time
```

Example:

```
myDate.AddDate(0, 0, 7 * weeksToAdd)
```

Answer (score 29):

You need to convert `weeksToAdd` into a `time.Duration`:

```
myDate.Add(time.Hour * 24 * 7 * time.Duration(weeksToAdd))
```

In Go, [defined types](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Type_definitions) cannot be used interchangeably even though `time.Duration` is technically defined as an `int64`.

Also, here, even though the numeric constants 24 and 7 are not explicitly typed, they can still be used as-is, see https://blog.golang.org/constants for an in-depth explanation.

See http://play.golang.org/p/86TFFlixWj for a running example.

As mentioned in comments and another answer, the use of `time.AddDate()` is preferable to `time.Add()` when working on duration superior to 24 hours, since `time.Duration` basically represents nanoseconds. When working with days, weeks, months and years, a lot of care has to be taken because of things such as daylight saving times, leap years, and maybe potentially leap seconds.

The documentation for `time.Duration` type and the associated constants representing units emphasize this issue (https://golang.org/pkg/time/#Duration):

> There is no definition for units of Day or larger to avoid confusion across daylight savings time zone transitions.

Comment: Time.Add does not operate in-place.

Comment: Well it's true, and I have fixed the example, but that's besides the point here.

Comment: thanks for the edit to explain why I can use 24 and 7. That was about to be my follow-up question.

Comment: You should use `AddDate` as suggested by @kostix. Using `Add` for days or weeks will not work correctly with DST and leap seconds. This is the reason why there are no `time.Duration` defined for a day or a week.

Comment: @kostya Good point. I did not really pay attention to this problem since I focused on the type conversion issue, but it's worth mentioning.

Comment: how subtract the date?

Comment: @DarlanDieterich use Time.Sub, it's right there in the doc.

Comment: @DarlanDieterich you could write `myDate.Add(-time.Hour * 24)`

Comment: Re: "In Go, type aliases cannot be used interchangeably even though `time.Duration` is technically an `int64`": That's not correct. Aliases *can* be used interchangeably, and if `time.Duration` were declared as an alias for `int64` then it could be used interchangeably with it. (That's what "alias" means.) But instead, `time.Duration` is declared as a distinct *defined type*, with `int64` as its *underlying type*. See https://go.dev/ref/spec#Type_declarations for more information about these concepts.

Comment: @ruakh interesting, after all these years, I didn't know about this distinction :)

Answer (score 0):

As an adding to **@kostix** answer.

`myDate` not changes when `AddDate` called. `AddDate` returns new date.

So, to change `myDate` you need to write:

```golang
myDate = myDate.AddDate(0, 0, 7 * weeksToAdd)
```