# How to add days to date

Tags: date, go

I want to get next day @ midnight of a given date.
So far I'm using:

```
givenDate.Add(time.Hour * time.Duration(24))
```

Problem is with certain timezones where I stay on the same day if I add 24h. In France, they change hours once in a while.

Is it safe to use the following to add a single day ?

```
time.Date(givenDate.Year(), givenDate.Month(), givenDate.Day()+1, 0, 0, 0, 0, loc)
```

`loc` being time.UTC in the given example.

Comment: Could you be more specific than "is it safe"? What doubts do you have about this method? Have you tested it?

Comment: I think the only edge case you need to take into account here is that some time never actually ocurred, and some times occured twice (1 hour on the daylight savings shift). From my knowledge all languages who shift does so at 2 AM though, so if your just interested in midnight then that should never be an issue.

Comment: Good to know about the 2am rule of thumb. 

@HymnsForDisco Yes I can clarify. I wonder if creating a date with time.Date(2020, 10, 40) is a reliable way of creating a date for instance, that is all extra days of the month will still be added to the date. I did some testing and it seems to work in my usecase.

Comment: https://golang.org/pkg/time/#Time.AddDate

Comment: related? [Add days to date in Go](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32998110/10197418)

Comment: Excuse me but what is the value of loc? Are some instruction missing from the source code?

Comment: @sensorario it's just my timezone variable. I'll update the example to clarify.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your proposed solution is "safe" and good:

```
t2 := time.Date(givenDate.Year(), givenDate.Month(), givenDate.Day()+1, 0, 0, 0, 0, loc)
```

You could make it faster with:

```
y, m, d := givenDate.Date()
t2 := time.Date(y, m, d+1, 0, 0, 0, 0, loc)
```

As [`Time.Date()`](https://golang.org/pkg/time/#Time.Date) returns you the date components in one call, and if you check the implementation, the [`Time.Year()`](https://golang.org/pkg/time/#Time.Year), [`Time.Month()`](https://golang.org/pkg/time/#Time.Month) and [`Time.Day()`](https://golang.org/pkg/time/#Time.Day) methods all call the same `Time.date()` (unexported) method under the hood (3 times in your case), just like `Time.Date()`.

[`time.Date()`](https://golang.org/pkg/time/#Date) documents that:

> Date returns the Time corresponding to
>
> ```
> yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss + nsec nanoseconds
> ```
>
> in the appropriate zone for that time **in the given location**.

So the documentation states that the location is taken into account, and if you pass 0 for hour, min, sec, nanonsec, those will be 0 **in the given zone**.